# Can't post data to php, Can't see why

Tags: php, javascript, html, email

I have some data from a form that is being sent to a php script to send an email, it is from a template but I think it is wrong. I have isolated the part of the code that is to blame. The specific piece of code seems to be the {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'userMessage':user_message} section (you can see where I have tried to fiddle with it with the commenting out on the third line). Any help would be appreciated!

```
 if(proceed) 
    {
        //data to be sent to server
        //post_data = {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'userMessage':user_message};
        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('contact_me.php',  {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'userMessage':user_message}, function(response){  

            //load json data from server and output message     
            if(response.type == 'error')
            {
                output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
            }else{
                output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';

                //reset values in all input fields
                $('#contact_form input').val(''); 
                $('#contact_form textarea').val(''); 
            }

            $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserName and the other variabiles don't need a single quote. It's just `{userName:user_name}`

And so forth

Comment: this did not seem to work, if you want to look it's www.sestina-services.co.uk/page

Comment: OK, what do you get if you do `console.log(response)` just inside the `$.post`?

Comment: I seem to have fixed it by taking out a line miles up about being in strict mode or something. Thank you for all your help